# Can't upload base64 string having special characters

Tags: java, android, string, base64, special-characters

I am stuck on a uploading issue. Server is in dotnet. Here is my iPhone code:

```
  -(NSString *)encodeToBase64String:(UIImage *)image {
    return [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)      base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
  }
```

This works well, but when I am trying to upload by my Android app, it always returns error from server when there some special characters in url like (=).

See below the code:

```
        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.contextParam.getResources(),
        ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);
        byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
        String ba1 = Base64.encodeToString(ba, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Log.e("Data:", ba1);
        
        
        
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "dsfsdfsd"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("filenamewithextension", "upload.png"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("newfilename", "Testing upload"));
        
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entityid", "10"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("filestream", ba1));

        Log.i(TAG, httppost.getURI().toString());
        Log.d(TAG, nameValuePairs.toString());
         
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,"UTF-8"));
        String base64EncodedCredentials = Base64.encodeToString(CREDENTIALS.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        httppost.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64EncodedCredentials);
        httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/largedata");
        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        return getStringFromInputStream(response.getEntity().getContent());

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return responseString;
```

With above code server always returns with "Request Error". Why might this be happening?

Aside: I can't change the server implementation, I have to find a solution on the Android side.

Comment: `application/largedata` looks like something you made up. `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` would be what's used by others for content like this. Otherwise for error produced by the server, do the debugging on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure because you didn't post your log, but I had a similar issue with an App I was working on for iOS. For HTTP, they have encoding rules. You may need to "percent-escape encode" your HTTPPost.

For example:

www.website.com/security/authorizekey?url=www.website.com?user=bob

When the above link was used as my URL Post, the rules of HTTP truncated my Post so that the server only received "www.website.com/security/authorizekey?url=www.website.com?user=" and truncated my user "bob".

According to [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt), the characters that should be permitted unescaped are the alphanumeric characters, plus "-", ".", "_", and "~":

```
2.3. Unreserved Characters

Characters that are allowed in a URI but do not have a reserved purpose are called unreserved. These include uppercase and lowercase letters, decimal digits, hyphen, period, underscore, and tilde.

unreserved  = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
```

See section 2 of the aforementioned [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) for more information.

Anyways, a solution might be similar to the following:

**Potential Solution:**

```
String query = URLEncoder.encode("apples oranges", "utf-8");
String url = "http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=" + query;
```

Comment: What does the URL you want to Post look like?